# Compare two dates in unix timestamps in mysql

Tags: mysql

The query works perfectly with greater than.

```
select RunId,count(ObjectId) 
From Run  
WHERE Created_On >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-12')  
group by RunId
```

But I want to compare the timestamps between two dates and when I tried the queries with less than its not fetching any rows.

```
select RunId,count(ObjectId) 
From Run 
WHERE Created_On <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-12')  
group by RunId

select RunId,count(ObjectId) 
From Run 
WHERE Created_On >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-12') and Created_On < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-12') 
group by RunId
```

Comment: but what are resiults you get when 1st query is executed? probably they all are from 2018?

Comment: No they are all not from 2018. it contains dates within all these ranges 2015-2018 I tried changing the date in second query to 2018 but i got no results.

Comment: why is the table name `Run` vs `RunFile` different in the two given queries? Perhaps has to do with the expected results?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake. its supposed to be run. its still not fetching any results and Im not sure whats wrong with 2nd and 3rd queries.

Comment: provide your table schema

Comment: and a couple of rows of data: one before 2015, one in the middle (supposed to be returned) , one after 2017. In other words, update your question with the data to have a proper MCVE

Comment: Works fine for me: https://rextester.com/NUABHD95618